# Can I get the full hierarchy of view models for a given element (without duplicates)?

Tags: knockout.js

I know I can do ko.dataFor(element) to get its view model, if any. What I need though is to get all view models as they appear in the $parents array for the given element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ko.contextFor what you are looking for: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html ?

The context returned by contextFor is a standard binding context, with access to all properties like $parents.